# About simpleXML_load_file

Tags: php, simplexml

i am new php developer and i have a question for you.

i try to do this:

```
$bookXML = simpleXML_load_file("<book_reference>
                                    <number>19761</number>
                               </book_reference>",'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA );
 if($bookXML==FALSE)
       echo  '<br> false';
```

and take fale!

can you help me?

i use php 5.4.7

Answer (score 1):

You should use `simplexml_load_string` because you are trying to generate the simple xml element object using the string instead of a file

[simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) — Interprets a string of XML into an object

Comment: but if an use a link that print the same XML, i have the same problem.